# Using nginx's allow/deny rules with incapsula

Tags: nginx

If you use incapsula, it appears that nginx will see all incoming request coming from their CDN IP ranges. However, incapsula passes an incap-client-ip header that could be used to differentiate between 'good' and 'bad' ips.

How do you set up nginx to say, block everything except one IP?

Answer (score 1):

You can use nginx's HttpRealIP module for this:

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRealipModule

You can set the header name with the directive

```
real_ip_header <headername>;
```

and setup the source IPs from which the header gets extracted with

```
set_real_ip_from 1.2.3.4/24;
```

You find the correct IPs to set it up for here:

http://support.incapsula.com/entries/20199668-Restricting-direct-access-to-your-website-Incapsula-s-IP-addresses-

The module will rewrite the source address with the one from the header, so you can use the standard deny syntax from nginx afterwards.